# Terminal -bash alias error after installing anaconda on macOS

Tags: python-3.x, bash, macos, terminal, anaconda

I have a MacBook Pro with macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (18G95)
I installed Anaconda with python on my system.
Since then, when ever i open my terminal, i get these messages.

```
Last login: Sat Oct  5 22:53:55 on console
You have new mail.
bash: alias: added: not found
-bash: alias: by: not found
-bash: alias: Anaconda3: not found
-bash: alias: 2019.07: not found
-bash: alias: installer: not found
(base) Ayushs-MacBook-Pro:~ Ayush$
```

Installing Anaconda has messed with my .bash_profile somehow.
These are the contents of my .bash_profile

```
# Homebrew
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/Ayush/Downloads/ayush-profectus-b02fa250957f.json

# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/Users/Ayush/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' ]; then source '/Users/Ayush/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '/Users/Ayush/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc' ]; then source '/Users/Ayush/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'; fi

# for complier
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin:$PATH
alias gcc='gcc-8'# added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/Ayush/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/Ayush/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/Ayush/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/Ayush/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

What does it means? Will it hamper my system in anyway,
How can i remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
alias gcc='gcc-8'# added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer
```

to

```
alias gcc='gcc-8'
# added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer
```